# Is it possible to determine the process id of specific entry in cron_schedule?

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, cron

I'm working on troubleshooting and cleaning up problematic cron jobs.  It's fairly often for some jobs to fail and leave their entry with a status of `running` in `cron_schedule`.  Meanwhile there are other jobs which are very slow, but do eventually complete.

I'd like to have a quick way to locate jobs in `cron_schedule` whose cron process is no longer running (e.g. find all running cron_scudule entries that aren't actually running).

So far I've been unable to find a way to correlate a magento cron job with the linux process which started it, is there a way, or would I need to build this myself?

Comment: What have you tried? I don't see any way to see from a PHP perspective which cron is falsely identified as running.

Comment: I've explored the database as well as poked around code for any hint of it capturing the pid of the job.  At the moment the workaround I use is to disable cron, wait ~30 minutes (long enough for healthy cron tasks to complete), kill the remaining cron processes, then restart cron--it works but it's crude

Comment: There is no way to do this. But I think you can use http://php.net/manual/de/function.getmypid.php to get the PID and implement an observer at the begin of the cronjob to write this PID into the database to the cronjob.